# Create a dynamic datatable dashboard with dynamic values in cells

Tags: javascript, python, django, plotly-dash

My website needs to display a dashboard (made of a datatable) on a webpage, in which the data will evolve really quickly (1 to 2 seconds). The data are received from a rabbitmq message queue.

I have successfully achieved it with Dash. Everything works well, but I have one major problem. Dash seems to be really slow when there is a huge amount of data (approximately 300 columns and 5000 rows in my case) that are regularly updated.

As far as I went, I think that the major lack of speed comes from the fact that the values pushed in the datatables are in a dictionary and not dynamic (not an in-cell modification), so all the javascript loads slowly and is not that stable.

Which leads me to this question: what would be the best way to achieve the goals mentioned above?

I thought that using Django and creating a custom javascript datatable could do the job but I would like to get some advice and ideas before starting to code that (really) time consuming solution.

Comment: Firstly I don't think displaying 5000 rows, or 300 columns is a good idea. No human can consume that much data in one go. You should figure out ways to segment the columns (perhaps into categories?) so that the user can choose what they want to see, and then paginate the results so that they don't get overwhelmed with 5000 rows.

Comment: I have to agree with @MattEllen, you're talking about 1.5 million cells. Finding ways to break that up will not only reduce the burden of keeping things updated, but also make it easier for your users to consume the data.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your replies ! But I can assure you that I need to have this amount of data. Even if, I know, I will not display all of them at the same time (maybe only 30 columns but all the rows), Dash is too slow because the whole structure is each time actualized. My main point is here to find a way to have a structure where only the content of the cells is modified. Which led me to this question I asked : is there a proper way to do so ?